# Having trouble using astroquery's Vizier.query_region?

Tags: astropy

I'm having some trouble getting a Vizier search using astropy to work. I'm looking for all sources nearby MWC 614 from the Gaia EDR3 database:

```
Vizier.query_region("MWC 614", radius = 480.0 * u.arcsecond, catalog = "I/350/gaiaedr3")
```

But it keeps returning an empty TableList, despite the fact that when I search without the catalog restriction, I can clearly see the "I/350/gaiaedr3" catalog available:

[image]

What makes it more confusing is that this code was working fine this morning! I haven't changed it at all, and yet it's suddenly stopped working. Does anyone have any idea as to what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me, though. There is a possibilty that the Vizier might have been having issues with its server. Please find the output of the above code [image: here]

Comment: Thank you for the response! For some reason it's working now; you're right that it's probably just a server issue. Either way, I'm just glad it's working!